# How does multiset store duplicate elements?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, c++14

I know that in c++, the Set template stores the elements as a balanced red black tree. But I would like to know how would multiset store duplicate element. For example, it could store 1,1,2,3 as the following

```
    1
   / \
  1   2
       \
        3
```

or as

```
  1
   \
    1
     \
      2
       \
        3
```

Comment: Examine the source code of the library.

Comment: The internals of map and set are not fixed, but the traditional implementation is a balanced red-black tree.

Comment: @Ron But that would make the implementation of the iterator much more difficult than allowing multiples.

Comment: @Ron I think they are stored as trees. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1237361/how-sets-multisets-maps-and-multimaps-work-internally

Comment: @Ron `unordered_multiset` is not a tree, but `multiset` (probably) is

Comment: Hint: one of those diagrams is not a *balanced* tree, and the other *is*

Comment: @Caleth This is what I would like to know, is multiset stored as a balanced binary tree or just as a BST?

Comment: Probably a red-black tree for unique elements with a list attached to any node that has duplicates.  But as long as the time constraints are met implementations are allowed to do what they like.  You need to look at the source for your implementation.

Comment: @RichardCritten I think this is the most probable solution. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A sensible implementation of the standard library will have *one* data-structure implementing all four of `map`, `multimap`, `set` and `multiset`. The differences in public members boil down to "how do we compare `value_type` instances?" "what is the result of a duplicate `insert`?"

Because of the complexity requirements, it is generally a balanced binary tree.

As a sketch of how to adapt a `BalancedTree`:

```
template <typename Value, typename Compare, typename Allocator>
class BalancedTree { ... };

template<
    class Key,
    class T,
    class Compare = std::less<Key>,
    class Allocator = std::allocator<std::pair<const Key, T> >
> class map
{
public:
  using value_type = std::pair<const Key, T>;
  class value_compare 
  { 
    value_compare(Compare c) : c(c) {}
    bool operator()( const value_type& lhs, const value_type& rhs ) const
    {
      return c(lhs.first, rhs.first);
    }
    Compare c;
  }

  std::pair<iterator, bool> insert(value_type vt)
  {
    node n(vt);
    auto pos = bt.insert_point(n);
    if (value_comp()(*pos, vt))
      return { bt.splice(pos, n), true };
    return { pos, false };
  }

private:
  BalancedTree<value_type, value_compare, Allocator> bt;
}

template<
    class T,
    class Compare = std::less<T>,
    class Allocator = std::allocator<T>
> class multi_set
{
public:
  using value_type = T;
  iterator insert(value_type vt)
  {
    node n(vt);
    auto pos = bt.insert_point(n);
    return bt.splice(pos, n);
  }

private:
  BalancedTree<T, Compare, Allocator> bt;
}
```